# I need example code for C++ connector to set "mysql_options"

Tags: c++, mysql

How to set timeout with mySQL C++ connector ?
I tried this.. but it is compile error.

```
error: ‘class sql::Driver’ has no member named ‘mysql_options’
error: ‘MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_FILE’ was not declared in this scope
```

code is here.

```
driver = get_driver_instance();
driver->mysql_options(MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_FILE, "/my.cnf");
con = driver->connect(host, user, password);
```

I read this page ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-options.html )
but This page has no C++ "Example"...

I need help !

Answer (score 1):

I find a way for it by myself.. : )
it worked at good.

```
    driver = get_driver_instance();

    sql::ConnectOptionsMap connection_properties;
    connection_properties ["hostName"] = host;
    connection_properties ["userName"] = user;
    connection_properties ["password"] = password;
    connection_properties ["OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT"] = 10;
    con = driver->connect(connection_properties);
```